# How to get the desired shape of CSS elements

Tags: css

I need to make a shape like this from a div.[image]

How can I do this with CSS ?.

Comment: did you try something yet?

Comment: Check out clip-path, have a go and when you get stuck put your code so far and an explanation of what isn't correct about the result in your question then we can help.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe `clip-path` is a option, but in most cases it's best to use a image/ svg.

More info on `clip-path`: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/clip-path